# base64 encoded then decoded failing

Tags: php, android, mysql

Here is the `base64` encoded smilies generated form my android phone and saved into `MySQL` when I try to display it in browser first I need to check if the string is `base64` encoded then I decoded and print it, but below code fails to

```
$mystring = "8J+YgPCfmInwn5iZ8J+YkPCflIfwn5Oi8J+OtfCfjqfwn5C18J+QiPCfpoTwn5CX8J+MjfCfl7vw\nn4+f8J+PofCfj4Himb/wn5uC8J+atA==\n";

if (base64_encode(base64_decode($mystring)) == $mystring) {
    echo base64_decode($mystring);
} else {
    echo  $mystring;
}
```

but if I directly decode same string and print it works

```
echo base64_decode($mystring);
// output ♿
```

however same code worked for iOS phone generated smiles.

```
$mystring = "8J+YgvCfkoHwn5iK8J+RqeKAjfCfkanigI3wn5Gn8J+ZiPCfpKPwn5mJ8J+QvPCfkLbwn5CT8J+MmeKaoe+4j/CfjY7wn42U8J+NlfCfpYPimr3vuI8=";

if(base64_encode(base64_decode($mystring)) == $mystring) {
    echo base64_decode($mystring);
} else {
    echo  $mystring;
}

//output  ‍‍⚡️⚽️
```

I don't understand what is the problem with this block:

```
if(base64_encode(base64_decode($mystring)) == $mystring)
```

Comment: `but below code fails to` You are not telling what fails or goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(base64_encode(base64_decode($mystring)) == $mystring)
```

You cannot compare the content of two strings in that way.

Use `strcmp()` function.

Moreover you cannot check in this way if $mystring is base64 encoded.

You will always get true as encoding a string and then decoding the result will always deliver the original string.

Comparing wil only tell you if encoding/decoding works.